# Why are some syntactic language extensions not enabled by default in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

For example, ViewPatterns or LambdaCase, it's purely syntactic and does not add any niche functionality.

Comment: everyone wonders the same... xD.

Comment: Likely eventually when a new Haskell report is written, some features will be added to the language.

Answer (score 9):

[Haskell is a standard, but GHC is a compiler.](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/) Even though GHC is pretty much the only major supported Haskell compiler, it does not define the language. However, there are features that they want to add to it, so they add it in the form of language extensions. They're called language **extensions** because they're not part of the standard, so GHC doesn't want to support them by default in order to be more compliant to the standard.